# Como puedo simplificar estas condiciones, ¿hay alguna manera?

Tags: python, django, revisión-de-código

¿Hay alguna manera de simplificar estas condiciones a una más corta?

```
    saldo_mes_corriente= CreditoBd.objects.filter(fecha_reporte=fecha_cierre).aggregate(Sum('saldo_credito'))
    saldo_mes_anterior= CreditoBd.objects.filter(fecha_reporte=fecha_cierre_anterior).aggregate(Sum('saldo_credito'))

    if saldo_mes_corriente > saldo_mes_anterior:
        icono_saldo = '+'
    else:
        if saldo_mes_corriente < saldo_mes_anterior:
            icono_saldo = '-'
        else:
            icono_saldo = '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La única recomendación que te haría sería utilizar `elif`, y de esa forma evitar anidar ese condicional:

```
if saldo_mes_corriente > saldo_mes_anterior:
    icono_saldo = '+'
elif saldo_mes_corriente < saldo_mes_anterior:
    icono_saldo = '-'
else:
    icono_saldo = '0'
```

Es preferible no sacrificar legibilidad, porque puede que logres acortar tu código pero si al final es más difícil de leer, no habrás ganado mucho.

Comment: Gracias por tu recomendación.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que puedas simplificar mucho. Simplemente como una alternativa puedes usar la sintaxis del operador ternario:

```
icono_saldo = "+" if saldo_mes_corriente > saldo_mes_anterior else\
              "-" if saldo_mes_corriente < saldo_mes_anterior else "0"
```

Otra cosa es que la perdida de legibilidad lo merezca. A nivel de eficiencia las diferencias entre tu código, operador ternario o un `elif` son despreciables.

Comment: Gracias por tu recomendación, por la pérdida de legibilidad prefiero aplicar elif.